# How to get date with category in ConsoleTVs/Charts?

Tags: laravel

error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::provinces does not exist.
```

Code:

```
  $data = App\Protection::with('provinces');
    $protection = Charts::create('bar', 'chartjs')
        ->title('title')
        ->elementLabel('total')
        ->dimensions(0, 300)
        ->labels($data->provinces()
        ->pluck('title')
        ->implode(' '))
        ->values($data->pluck('benefit_kind'))
        ->responsive(false);
```

Protection Model:

```
class Protection extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function provinces()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Province::class);
}
public function districts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(District::class);
}
```

}

Comment: Can i see the model (Protection.php) ?

Comment: I shared Protection model

Comment: it may be foreign key issue. use actual path of the model and keys like this  ```$this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\Floor', 'as_floor_id', 'hr_floor_id'); ```

Comment: I'm using this Package [ https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/tree/5.4.0/docs/5 ]

Comment: I tried this code but not worked  `$data = App\Protection::with('provinces')->get();`